# how do I duplicate a project in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a very simple question. Normally in other programs, such as word, you can just simply save the document under a different resulting in two separate documents. However, this doesn't work for AnyLogic. Does anyone know how to duplicate a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do file save as it will create a new alp file for you

[image]

But for it to be a truly *different* model you need to change the Java Package to something unique... See how it is kept as `model24` in my screenshot

But be careful it can have some unwanted consequences in a very complex model and you will need to fix these manually, but all doable